# how can i create automatic id /autonumber on my form, without using models on laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel

Excuse me, I'm newbie in laravel, I learn laravel 2 weeks ago and I have some problems, maybe I can find a solution in here.
so I want to make some autonumber ID without using models.

This is the example:
BRG-0001
BRG-0002
++

This is my view

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_barang" name="id_barang" value="{{'BRG-'.$kd}}"  maxlength="200" readonly>`
```

And this is my controller

```
public function barangStore(request $request){{
  $q=DB::table('barang'->select(DB::raw('MAX(RIGHT('id_barang',5)) as kode')); $kd = "";
  
  if($q->count()>0)
  {
      foreach($q->get() as $k)
      {
          $tmp = ((int)$k->kode)+1;
          $kd = sprintf("%04s", $tmp);
      }
  }
  else
  {
          $kd = "0001";
  }
    
  return $view ('barang', compact('barang','kd');
}
```

But when i back into my views it's getting errors and said undefined variable $kd. Can anybody helps me/explain me how should i fix?

Comment: check the Parentheses  you have 2 in the beginning, and 1 is missing at the end

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing this at all. What happens when 2 users open the page, they will get the same id. 1st user will submit fine, but 2nd user will submit the form with already taken id.